# Underflow in R, sum of logartihm of probabilities

Tags: r

How  to calculate the logarithm of the sum of the probabilities, i.e. ln(p1 + p2), where p1 = a very small number and p2 = a very small number.  Using the values of lp1 = ln(p1) and lp2 = ln(p2)

If you p1 and p2 are very small numbers underflow will happen. How to avoid this?

Answer (score 4):

In general the following tips are useful for taking logs in `r`:

- If you are taking `log(1+x)` for a very small `x` there is a function `log1p` that is more accurate (see also `expm1`).
- `log(x^a)` = `a*log(x)`
- `log(a*x)` = `log(a) + log(x)`
- Calculating log(x) for small x is fine. `log(1e-308)` does not suffer from underflow. Calculating `exp(-1e308)` is different, but that is far smaller than any representable answer anyway.

One way to solve your question might be (assuming `p1` and `p2` are less than $10^-308$) is to calculate log(p2) and p1/p2, and then

log(p1 + p2) = log(1 + p1/p2) + log(p2)

calculate the first term using `log1p` and you already have the second.